# how to integrate facebook PHP SDK (v4) to my ZF1 site

Tags: facebook, zend-framework

please help me to integrate facebook PHP SDK (v4) to my ZF1 site. I searched and found some tutorials but all of those where on older version(SDK version 3.1.1) not the recent v4. I want to create a facebook application that loads contents(list of products) from my existing zend framework website to facebook page that i manage.I am stuck and i dont have idea on how to integrate facebook client library in zend framework. Also any help on how to fetch products from my website to facebook page is appreciated.

Comment: What do you need help with? What does your code like and what is your problem?

Comment: I have edited my question...hope its clear now. Please check now

Comment: So what does your code look like?

Comment: I have'nt started integrating php sdk client library... just downloaded SDK version 4, copied contents inside src folder(folder named facebook) inside library folder of my zend project.